# How to send mail multiple selected users

Tags: html, css, arrays, laravel-5

I have a meetings table where I am storing meeting information and where I can select a meeting between 2 types of user **visitor type user and host type user**. I have a many to many relationships between users and meeting that's why I have a pivot table meeting_user. I need to send mail all of the selected users for one meeting.

I am trying to send email using this but it's storing the **meeting_id** into **notifiable_id** column of db. so how can I store **users_id** in the **notifiable_id** column of db.

```
$meetings->save();

    $meetings->users()->attach($request->user_id);

    $users = Meeting::with('users')->get();
\Mail::to($user->send(New NewMeeting($meetings('id')));
```

Comment: What does the `$meetings` variable store? One meeting or more?

Comment: @ thisiskelvin One meeting with multiple users.

Answer (score 1):

There are two scenarios in which you can send an email to users to the meeting:

1. When the user has been added to the meeting
2. When alerting all users (in bulk) of a meeting which they have been added to.

#### When emailing the user which has just been added

In the event where you would like to email the users once added, you can do the following:

```
...

$meeting = Meeting::find($meeting_id);

$user = User::find($request->user_id);

$meeting->users()->attach($user->id);

\Notification::send($user, new NewMeetingNotification($user));
```

This is to be added within code *which only* adds a user to a meeting, not multiple users.

#### When emailing all users within a meeting at once

In the event where you would like to email users, in bulk, once you've added all users, you can do the following.

```
...

$meeting = Meeting::with('users')->where('id', $meeting_id)->first();

$meeting->users()->each(function ($user, $key) {
    \Notification::send($user, new NewMeetingNotification($user));
});
```

`$meeting_id` being the meeting in question.

#### Notify User (Optional)

If the `user` model has the [notifiable](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/notifications#using-the-notifiable-trait) trait, you can change the code to:

```
...

$meeting = Meeting::with('users')->where('id', $meeting_id)->first();

$meeting->users()->each(function ($user, $key) {
    $user->notify(new NewMeetingNotification($user));
});
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Here for the first section it's showing an error `\Notification::send($meeting->users, new NewMeetingNotification($meeting->users);`  `syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ',' or ')'` and the secound one is storing the pivot table  id not the `user_id`

Comment: @Md.AbuZaman Updated answer for the first error. Did you mean second error?

Comment: @Md.AbuZaman Can you update your question with your `meetings` model file to see the relationships

Comment: In the first answer, there was a bracket missing but now it sending the notifications of all users. but I want to send the notification only a meeting with new users. And the secound answer it storing the `pivot tbale id` not the `user_id `

Comment: I mean when I am creating a meeting with 4 users I just want to sent the notifications with those 4 users.

Comment: @Md.AbuZaman I'm starting to understand. The second answer will do this. However, I am assuming the relationship between `meetings` and `users` may not be set correctly on the `meeting` model? Could you post your `meeting` model?

Comment: @thisiskelvinHere is Meeting Model `public function users(){

        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'meeting_user');
    }`

Comment: Could you change to `return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'meeting_user', 'meeting_id, 'user_id');` and see if it works. I think it may be causing a problem as the table needs to be `meetings_users` instead of `meeting_user`?

Comment: @thisiskelvinI replaced the model but still your this first answer sending notification of all users.

Comment: @Md.AbuZaman When testing, how many users have been created? How many attached to the meeting and how many was the email sent to?

Comment: I have some existing users. When iI creating I meeting I just selecting 2 visitors user and 3 host type users.

Comment: I have 10 users and when I creating a new meeting with 4 users it's sending the notificaton of al the 10 users.

Comment: Please see this images. https://drive.google.com/open?id=1JQKknmwNb7IdWFvVyaigFc-pr9MHKAkP

Comment: At the moment, every time you attach a user, it then sends out an email to all users. I'd assume you either want to send out an email on attach to the newly attached user, or you want to send an email to all users at a different time. My suggestion would be to either separate the login which adds a user to a meeting (and then send emails at a different stage in bulk), or only send one email out once the user is attached.

Comment: I have attached the selecting users for each meeting. And I just need to send those attached users only for that meeting. Then again I created another meeting then it again attached those new users and I just need to send mail to them. But your code sending mail 2-3 times of the same users.

Comment: Do you want to send the emails when the user is added to the meeting, or all at once?

Comment: I want to send the mail when users is added to the meeting. Like when I creating a meeting and select 4 users for a meeting I just need to send the mail to that 4 users with that meeting info.

Comment: @ thisiskelvin `Now it's showing  Undefined variable: meeting_id`

Comment: I dont know why you passing $user again in `new NewMeetingNotification($user)`

Comment: meeting_id refers to the id of the meeting in question, you will need to create the logic to retrieve this.

Comment: $user is passed to use the user details (eg name) in the email template. Do more research if you would like to include this in your email, otherwise take it out